# Moving old drive contents to an already-allocated drive via pvmove

Tags: linux, debian, lvm

In my setup, I've got 4x 3tb HDDs, and a brand new 10tb HDD which I'm attempting to offload one of the 3tb ones onto.

Current setup:

- `/dev/sda` - `/dev/sdd`: 3tb drives (with `/dev/sd*1` as their partitions)
- `/dev/sde`: OS ssd
- `/dev/sdf`: whole-disk 10tb physical volume, which was just allocated
- `storage`: the name for both the volume group and the logical volume

I added the 10tb to the volume group with the following commands:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdf
vgextend storage /dev/sd6
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/storage/storage
```

However I realized quite quickly that after allocating the free space from the 10tb to the volume group, that I could not do a `pvmove` from `/dev/sdd1` (3tb) to `/dev/sdf` (10tb):

```
rogue@devlynx:~$ sudo pvmove /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdf
  No free extents on physical volume "/dev/sdf".
  No specified PVs have space available
```

**So my question is** mostly about next steps from here; I want to move the <=3tb of content from `sdd1` to `sdf`, and then remove `sdd1` and `/dev/sdd` for use in another machine. I know pvmove is slow and have accomodated for that, but I'm also open to potentially faster methods.

Some more information added on:

`pvs`

```
  PV         VG      Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/sda1  storage lvm2 a--  2.73t    0
  /dev/sdb1  storage lvm2 a--  2.73t    0
  /dev/sdc1  storage lvm2 a--  2.73t    0
  /dev/sdd1  storage lvm2 a--  2.73t    0
  /dev/sdf   storage lvm2 a--  9.10t    0
```

`pvdisplay` for `/dev/sdf`:

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdf
  VG Name               storage
  PV Size               9.10 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2384383
  Free PE               0               # was allocated
  Allocated PE          2384383
  PV UUID               igt7bZ-dyIw-NQmq-Jd6Q-UDiV-FMcX-trHf9T
```

`vgdisplay`

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               storage
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        5
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                5
  Act PV                5
  VG Size               20.01 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              5245967
  Alloc PE / Size       5245967 / 20.01 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               0gr6VO-MjM7-vstz-1k0d-Y5pf-JWXa-YyHV42
```

Comment: Assuming you haven't extended the filesystem yet, just lvreduce the logical volume by enough space to handle the pvmove.  `lvreduce -L -3T storage/storage`, then run your pvmove.  If you have extended the filesystem, you'll have to shrink that first.

Comment: @yoonix Assuming that prioritizes unused extents (quick googling seems to confirm that), how would I check to ensure the filesystem wasn't extended? I didn't run any commands in addition to what was posted, but I get the idea now of reducing the logical volume to "make room" for offloading the 3tb

Comment: If you haven't run the command to extend filesystem, then it hasn't been extended. You can check `df -h` output versus the output of your logical volumes list command and you will see that the filesystem size and LV size are different.

Comment: Awesome, `df -h` confirmed that. Started `pvmove` with the proper available amount now. If you want to post everything as an answer I'll accept it, thanks!

Comment: Always run lvextend and especially lvreduce with `-r` option, which will extend/reduce FS if possible or fail. (In your case, it was useful you did not run it with the option though.)